# Marionette - How to access App region in Controller

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I had a simple backbone app which I am trying to turn into Marionette.

Have defined the App in app and added region there, also on initialize tried to get the AppRouter as below:

```
   iApp.addInitializer(function(options){
        // Add Router
        iApp.addRouter = new Mrouter();
    });
    iApp.on("start", function(options){
           Backbone.history.start();
    });
    iApp.addRegions({
        header : "#mainheader"
    });

Now in AppRouter added a method referenced in controller as below:
    define([
   'marionette',
   'backbone',
   'jquery',
    'controller/controller'   

   ],function(Marionette,Backbone,Router,Controller){
   var appRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        controller : new Controller(),
        appRoutes : {
            '' : 'mainpage'
        }
```

....

Now in Controller trying to access App region so that I can load the view as below:

```
define([
'marionette',
'backbone',
'underscore',
'jquery',
'../views/subviews/mheader',
'../mapp'
], function(Marionette,Backbone,_,$,Mheader,Iapp){

            var iController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
                initialize : function() {
                    console.log("Initialzier");
                },
                mainpage : function() {
                    Iapp.header.show(new Mheader());
                    // Add region or fix the view.
                },
                onClose : function() {
                    console.log("closing the contoller");

                }                
            });    
            return iController;
```

"header" in controller is not accessible, I guess I printed even the App it is coming null.

Question 1. - Does it not create circular dependency of App?
Question 2. - Why App is not accessible?

Comment: Also I think most of the time you would depend upon AppRouter or Controller to render views as oppose to be done in app.js. I could have done this in app.'s but don't really think it is good idea.   I went through - https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs but this assumes most of the dependency is due to vent - I think it can be region/layout also which creates the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this into mapp.js file:

```
iApp.start();
```

Comment: well It probably not in the code above but I do have iApp.start() in my main.js. Code is operationally working fine. But what I think controller is the one that would be rendering the views. So I need the access of iAPP in controller so that - I can work on the iApp region which i have added in app.js.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to get this working, as the post suggested - https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs - I added the require(mapp) which basically ensure the load of the app again. I am finally glad I am moving with marionette.

Answer (score -1):

You can asynchronously load the app inside index method of controller (wherever you need it) rather than adding it as a dependency of module

from below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42271316/911804